# Implementing argmin in Python for dictionaries

Tags: python, function, dictionary

This has likely been asked before, but does anyone know of an elegant way to implement argmin in Python? That is, given a dictionary D mapping integers to integers, I want to find the key k such that D[k] is minimized.

For example:

```
d = {1: 100, 2:200}
argmin(d) = 1
```

Answer (score 8):

```
def argmin(d):
    if not d: return None
    min_val = min(d.values())
    return [k for k in d if d[k] == min_val][0]

d = {1: 50, 2:100, 3:11}
min_index = argmin(d)
```

**EDIT**

`min` has an optional key parameter so you can use this instead:

```
min_index = min(d, key=d.get)
```

Comment: This is wrong and incredibly inefficient. It takes quadratic time, it uses `max` instead of `min`, and it uses `is` where it should use `==`.

Comment: I'm not saying it can't be improved. But how come it uses quadratic time? As I see it it is linear.

Comment: @user3267581: The original version calculated `min(z.values())` for every key.

Comment: Yeah, I did a `%timeit` in ipython and it was dramatically slower if you use `min(z.values())` in the list comprehension.